# Ordering of correlated normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am aware of the geometric argument for computing $\mathbb{P}(X >0, Y>0)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are correlated normal random variables with mean zero, but is there a similar result (approximation?) for a larger number of normal r.v.s? The co-variance matrix that I have in mind is
$$\begin{matrix}
3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{matrix}
$$
in dimension three and defined similarly in higher dimensions (threes along the diagonal and ones elsewhere).

Letting $X,Y,Z$ have a multivariate normal distribution with the above co-variance matrix $\mathbb{P}(X >0, Y>0, Z >0)$ is equal to $\mathbb{P}(U_1 > U_2, U_1>U_3)$ where $U_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $U_2,U_3 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ (with $U_1,U_2$ and $U_3$ all independent). Perhaps there is a way to exploit this? In the case of $U_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ it is clear that $\mathbb{P}(U_1 > U_2, U_1 > U_3) = 1/3$ since each of $U_1,U_2$ and $U_3$ has equal probability of being the largest of the three.

Comment: There is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379255/a-question-about-trivariate-normal-distribution/) version of the result that I am aware of.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you very much for sharing this link. Your solution is very interesting. It seems like the Inclusion / Exclusion Principle allows us to derive the probability of an odd number of correlated normal random variables ($n$ for definiteness) being greater or equal to zero provided we have the result for all smaller $n$. This approach will not work for even $n$ since the $-p$ will cancel on both sides. I find this quite surprising; we can go from even to odd, but not the other way. Do you have an (intuitive) explanation why this is the case?

Comment: I don't know. But you can take a look at Johnson-Kotz-Balakrishnan's *[Continuous Multivariate Distributions](https://books.google.com/books?id=EbPBXJ-N-m4C&lpg=PP1&dq=johnson%20kotz%20and%20balakrishnan%20multivariate%20continuous&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)* where the authors discuss **orthant probabilities** of multivariate normal distribution.